# Issues with Ubuntu FreeRadius

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, freeradius

I have a problem with FreeRadius I wrote a script to add users. When I want to restart the service with:

```
service freeradius restart
```

I get the following output:

```
top: Unknown instance:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the server in debug mode `/usr/sbin/freeradius -X` and examine the output to find out why there server is failing to start.